# PHP password login gets passwords from user input and password, but doesn't verify

Tags: php, t-sql, passwords

I have the php which pulls the correct login data, and the user input for the password, both of which are hashed. When the `password_verify()` is used, it says `false`. Error reporting returns no errors. I can't seem to find why its not working.

Stored password is: `$2y$10$pah82g8RHELhYP/MJEGNcuOFeg6u60.NUTigLSxrezhMMCAc7jvSi`

User Password hash is: `$2y$10$gd9GsmfchKKLwPX1jG.6YevuGZgSltLG7tfCW3WSklxBW6GTBxkxe`

Verify returns: `bool(false)`

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
//Defining variables
$usernameErr = $passErr = "";
$username = $password = "";

$loginBool = true;

// Error check the username
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
    if (empty($_POST["username"])) {
        $usernameErr = "Please enter a Username";
        $loginBool = false;
    } else {
        $username = test_input($_POST["username"]);
        //check if username only contains valid characters
        if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z0-9-_]*$/", $username)) {
            $usernameErr = "Only letters numbers and hyphens allowed";
            $loginBool = false;
        }
        $_SESSION["User"] = $username;
    }
    // Error check the password
    if(empty($_POST["password"])) {
        $passErr = "Please Enter a password";
        $loginBool = false;
    } else {
        $password = test_input($_POST["password"]);
        //Check if password has correct characters
        if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z0-9]*$/", $password)) {
            $passErr = "Password is not in correct format" ;
            $loginBool = false;
        }
        $password = hash_pass($password);
    }
    // Connecting to server if no errors present
    if ($loginBool = true) {
        $server = 'sql.rde.hull.ac.uk';
        $connectionInfo = array("Database"=>"rde_556278");
        $conn = sqlsrv_connect($server, $connectionInfo);
        // Query
        $describeQuery = "SELECT Username FROM Users WHERE Username = '$username';";

        $results = sqlsrv_query($conn, $describeQuery, array(), array("Scrollable" => "buffered"));
        //Checking if result is returned
        $rowCount = sqlsrv_num_rows($results);
        if($rowCount === false) {
            echo "error";
        }
        //checking only one result is returned
        else {
            if($rowCount == 1) {

                //Selecting password
                $describeQuery = "SELECT Pass FROM UserInfo WHERE Username = '$username'";

                $results = sqlsrv_query($conn, $describeQuery, array(), array("Scrollable" => "buffered"));
                //Checking if result is returned
                $rowCount = sqlsrv_num_rows($results);
                if($rowCount === false) {
                    echo "error";
                }
                else {
                    $rowCount = sqlsrv_num_rows($results);
                    if($rowCount === false) {
                        echo "error";
                    }
                    else {
                        if($rowCount ==1) {
                            while($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($results, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)) {
                                $storedPass = $row['Pass'];
                            }

                            echo $storedPass;
                            echo "<br>". $password;
                            $verification = password_verify($password, $storedPass);
                            echo "<br>";
                            var_dump($verification);

                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            else {
                $usernameErr = "User Not Found";
            }
        }
    }
    else {
    }
}
//sanitizing data simple
function test_input($data) {
    $data = trim($data);
    $data = stripslashes($data);
    $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
    return $data;
}
//hashing the pass
function hash_pass($hashed_pass) {
        $hashed_pass = password_hash($hashed_pass, PASSWORD_BCRYPT);
    return $hashed_pass;
}

?>
```

AT the moment, SQL injection is not a concern, this is purely to get the verification correct. After this is complete, then injection will be worried about. PHP version is most recent. Database is SQL Server (T-SQL).

EDIT 1 ------------

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
//Defining variables
$usernameErr = $passErr = "";
$username = $password = "";

$loginBool = true;

// Error check the username
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
    if (empty($_POST["username"])) {
        $usernameErr = "Please enter a Username";
        $loginBool = false;
    } else {
        $username = $_POST["username"];
        if (!preg_match("/^[\w-_+]*$/", $username)) {
            $usernameErr = "Only letters numbers and hyphens allowed";
            $loginBool = false;
        }
        //Setting session variable
        else {
            $_SESSION["User"] = $username;
        }

    }
    //Error checking the password
        if(empty($_POST["password"])) {
            $passErr = "Please Enter a password";
            $loginBool = false;
        } 
        else {
            //Check if password has correct characters
            if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z0-9]*$/", $password)) {
                $passErr = "Password is not in correct format" ;
                $loginBool = false;
            }
            else {
                $hashed_pass = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_BCRYPT);
            }
        }
         //if no errors present, connect to and check user
        if($loginBool == true) {
            $server = 'sql.rde.hull.ac.uk';
            $connectionInfo = array("Database"=>"rde_556278");
            $conn = sqlsrv_connect($server, $connectionInfo);
            $SelectQuery = "SELECT Username FROM Users WHERE Username = ?";

            //Initialize params and prepare statement
            $params = array($username);
            $results = sqlsrv_query($conn, $SelectQuery, $params, array("Scrollable" => "buffered"));
            if($results === false) {
                die (print_r(sqlsrv_errors(), true));
            }
            else {
                while ($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($results, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)) {

                    $rowCount = sqlsrv_num_rows($results);
                    if ($rowCount != 1) {

                    }
                    else {
                        $SelectQuery = "SELECT Pass FROM UserInfo WHERE Username = ?";
                         $params = array($username);
                         $results = sqlsrv_query($conn, $SelectQuery, $params, array("Scrollable" => "buffered"));
                        if($results === false) {
                            die (print_r(sqlsrv_errors(), true));
                        }
                        else {
                            while ($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($results, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)) {

                                $rowCount = sqlsrv_num_rows($results);
                                $storedPass = $row['Pass'];
                                echo "Stored Password is " . $storedPass . "<br><br>";
                                echo "User password is " . $hashed_pass;
                            }
                            $verification = password_verify($hashed_pass, $storedPass);
                            echo "<br><br>";
                            var_dump($verification);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
}
?>
```

Reformatted code, according to comments, still returns false on verify

EDIT 2 -------------------

```
        if($loginBool == true) {
            $server = 'sql.rde.hull.ac.uk';
            $connectionInfo = array("Database"=>"rde_556278");
            $conn = sqlsrv_connect($server, $connectionInfo);
            $SelectQuery = "SELECT Username, Pass FROM UserInfo WHERE Username = ?";

            //Initialize params and prepare statement
            $params = array($username);
            $results = sqlsrv_query($conn, $SelectQuery, $params, array("Scrollable" => "buffered"));
            if($results === false) {
                die (print_r(sqlsrv_errors(), true));
            }
            else {
                while ($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($results, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)) {
                    $user = $row['Username'];
                    $PassFromDatabase = $row['Pass'];
                    echo $user . "<br><br>";
                    echo $PassFromDatabase;

                    $rowCount = sqlsrv_num_rows($results);
                    if ($rowCount == 1) {
                        $verified = password_verify($password, $PassFromDatabase);
                        var_dump($verified);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

changed the code to pull the required data in one go, make it easier to read. Bool still returns false, hash from database is pulled correctly, as is the username.

Comment: did you trim input? did you check input via `password_verify()` manually? check first example of this [link](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php) it in writephponline.com

Comment: the function test_input() is trimming it? at least that's what I think its doing?

Comment: `test_input` is a mess. Don't use that. Parameterize your queries. `$loginBool = true` is an assignment not comparison. `^[a-zA-Z0-9-_]*$` can also just be `^[\w-]*$` You probably want `+` though

Comment: $login bool has been fixed, and test_input now removed. At the moment, I have said queries are not being parameted until verification works, as this is only a project

Comment: ahh nvm, now is a good a time as ever to learn parametrized queries